# std::list contains millions of null objects that were never added

Tags: memory-leaks, c++-cli, stdlist

For some reason, my std::list contains over 1000000 empty objects (according to the debugger) midway through my program's execution.

I've put breakpoints on `push_front()` and `push_back()`, but neither of them are called 1000000 times, and my actual code only ever uses those two functions.

I'm afraid I don't know what code to copy here - here's the actual location of the resulting `System.AccessViolationException`, but... well, I'll copy in anything anyone asks for.

```
//Model.h
struct Update {
public:
    double pEgivenH, pE;
    int E;

    Update(double, double, int);
    Update &operator=(const Update &rhs);
    int operator==(const Update &rhs) const;
    int operator<(const Update &rhs) const;
};

//UpdateButton.h
System::Void UpdateButton::UpdateButton_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    double pEgivenH, pE;
    int EID;

    System::String^ pEHStr = pEHholder->Text;
    System::String^ pEStr = pEholder->Text;
    System::String^ eviStr = eviholder->Text;

    pEgivenH = double::Parse(pEHStr);
    pE = double::Parse(pEStr);

    std::string evistr = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(eviStr);
    EID = m->registerEvidence(evistr);

    h->updateHypothesis(Update::Update(pEgivenH, pE, EID));//This line
}

//Model.cpp
double Hypothesis::updateHypothesis(Update u) {
    history.push_back(u); //This line.
    currentP *= u.pEgivenH / u.pE;
    return currentP;
}
```

Debugger data:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
The program '[4500] AutoBayes.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

EDIT: I added debugging code to `Hypothesis::updateHypothesis(Update)`. The new function reads

```
//Model.cpp
double Hypothesis::updateHypothesis(Update u) {
    System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(history.begin(), history.end());
    history.push_back(u); //This line.
    currentP *= u.pEgivenH / u.pE;
    return currentP;
}
```

The program now crashes on the debugging line, and I get

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in AutoBayes.exe
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in AutoBayes.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Stack trace indicates it's crashing on `::end()`.

Comment: Can you also paste the debugger information. It may help us to get clue on what exactly you are looking at.

Comment: That what you wanted?

Comment: The debugger is using the builtin counter in the `list`. Try using `std::distance( l.begin(), l.end() )` to verify whether there are actually items there. If not, or if that operation crashes, you probably have a buffer overflow from whatever is allocated below the list object.

Comment: ... Well _that's_ interesting. Updated.

Comment: Um, does WriteLine even work with iterators? That looks kinda weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can trust the debugger? Are you working with a debug build with hybrid debugging enabled?

Assuming that's all fine, most likely the list has been corrupted somehow. Maybe you have a buffer overflow somewhere that overwrote it. Maybe `h` is a dangling pointer. Something like this is the most likely error here, but it means you will have to look at more code than just the line that is crashing.

For the record, `Update::Update(pEgivenH, pE, EID)` should be just `Update(pEgivenH, pE, EID)`, but that's unlikely to be the source of the error: it should just fail to compile.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. I'm a newbie to C++ working with Microsft Visual Studio 2012, so I'd like to _assume_ so...

Comment: Also, `Update(, , )` fails to compile, while `Update::Update(, ,)` succeeds. Not sure what that's about, then.

Comment: Oh, I'm pretty sure it does, somewhere in some base class of UpdateButton. So the correct form would be `AutoBayes::Update(, ,)`.

Comment: No, it doesn't; UpdateButton inherits from Button. Update is an entirely different class. And `AutoBayes::Update(, ,)` just returns `Namespace "AutoBayes" has no member "Update"`.

Comment: It's finding this Update method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx which is in Control, which is a base class of Button and thus a base class of UpdateButton. And if your Update class isn't in namespace AutoBayes, then use whatever proper qualified name will find it. ::Update, maybe. I don't know, because you didn't include the namespaces in your code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that it was indeed a memory problem - UpdateButton was constructed using a pointer to a list element, which I got by getting the address of an object created in a for-each loop. Apparently that creates copies of the list elements; when I replaced the for-each with a for-iterator and defined

```
Hypothesis h = *it;
```

the program continued to fail, but when I used

```
Hypothesis &h = *it;
```

instead, I got my persistent pointer.

Comment: The problem was the reference all along; with a reference it should work with the for-each loop too.